# Particle animation over a photo

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-video

I have to create a web page with an image of an opened hand and a storm of particles over it. Clicking on three buttons will change the particles (wood, plastic or water particles).

Currently, I created a video for the particles and put it on a canvas to render the transparency (using https://github.com/m90/seeThru) but I see a great lack in the performances of the page, and the video has difficult to  run at 30fps.

Which is the BEST practice to achieve this effect with great performances?

[image: The particles float over the opened hand]

Comment: You're probably pushing the technology further than it's able to go, really. I'd probably do it in one of two ways. One, have a gif of the particles. Or two, build a particle cloud using a jQuery script (like http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php or something) and replace the words/tags with individual sprites of your wood chips, etc.

Comment: Yes, video + particle animation will likely stress most viewing devices. Instead, how about having a static "shirt & tie" background. Over the shirt & tie have an "open hand" image and give it some liveliness by moving it slightly. Finally animate your particles over the open hand. The graphic particles can be pulled from a spritesheet.